# Don't know what to call this crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

I seem to have forgotten the name of this puzzle. The only thing I do remember is that every answer is different. Can you find out what it's called? Why do you think that name is appropriate?

**Across**
7. Expedition is coming back, having toured region in the east of Africa (6)
12. Like a presidential office's evacuation, boycotted by band from Athens (4)
13. A part of the cuisine of Japan, not Norway's west coast (5)
14. Spooner's adding folds in club – making a clubhouse, perhaps? (7,5)
15. Red Garland's Essential Quintet: "White Winter" (5)
16. Obama binned a piece of ceremonial attire (4)
18. Where some Floridians are home and escape? (4)
20. Bananas lay at part of Russian-controlled territory (5)
23. Assimilate disheartened minority group's member in Egypt (4)
25. Provide education for way to transport people (5)
26. Young adult to fly from Philippine island westward to get substance used in some bars (5)
27. I was lost in silent thoughtfulness (4)
29. Moral principle on the Forum... and here (5)
32. Children wait for this in excitement before parents kiss (1-3)
36. Country girl making small oversight at the beginning (4)
39. She sailed with Nina's dad, having lost diamonds after some beer (5)
40. An unfair icon misrepresented multinational collective (7,5)
42. Exploration of social science after end of semester (5)
43. Primarily aviators' lingo for A? (4)
44. Foolish deputee's head I shot exploded (6)

**Down**
1. Tour sea between Europe and Africa, shaped like a hemisphere (5)
2. Important figure in the story about Apple, Mr Jobs? No saint! (3)
3. Predatory seabird is the first to break the sound barrier, they say (6)
4. Bananas lay at part of Russian-controlled territory (5)
5. Heraldic pattern of very distinct quality (4)
6. Nubian leader welcomed aboard Mesopotamian kingdom's vessels (4)
7. Story supported by NASA's top astronomer (5)
8. Beginning to accept politician's sources of feedback (4)
9. What a soccer lover has when playing? (1,4)
10. Rapper Ice-T entertaining university in Texas (4)
11. Cree occasionally visiting capital of Italy, large and prosperous European country (7)
17. Broadway lyricist Lerner's back in Panama? (4)
18. Leaving hotel, Kathy exchanged currency (4)
19. "Pat", alternatively (3)
21/41. I stop dancing, essentially; Stafford blows the whistle (4,3)
22. Cree occasionally visiting capital of Italy, large and prosperous European country (7)
23. Tesla created one; it runs on electricity, carbon and fossil fuel (4)
24. "Pat", alternatively (3)
28. Paper animal haphazardly put together (6)
30. Repair short block that has come up in faulty environment (5)
31. Provide education for way to transport people (5)
33. Last name of Caribbean native who sings remix of "Jammin'" without drum backing (5)
34. Maybe Hamlet is protecting a legendary hero's mother (5)
35. Do (or another note) coming up (4)
37. AA assembly's introduction: "Dry wine is on the rise" (4)
38. Rocker Scott's turned out to be a pretentious type (4)
39. Not at all like King Kong climbing up the Empire State? (4)
41. *(See 21 down)*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An appropriate name for this puzzle is:

> **DEJA VU (BY JAFE)** - this can be read off via the 6 dead-ends in the first and last rows of the crossword.

Why is it appropriate?

> Because the puzzle contains 4 pairs of clues with identical wordplay wording and enumeration but different answers!

The finished grid:

> [image: Completed crossword]

Clue explanations:

> **Across**
>  7. **Expedition** is coming back, having toured region in the east of Africa (6) **SAFARI** = IS< around [AFAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afar_Region)
>  12. **Like a presidential office**'s evacuation, boycotted by band from Athens (4) **OVAL** = (-[rem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.E.M.))OVAL
>  13. A part of the cuisine of Japan, not Norway's west coast (5) **ARAME** = A RAME(-n) &lit!
>  14. Spooner's adding folds in club – making a **clubhouse, perhaps**? (7,5) **MEETING PLACE** = Spoonerism of PLEATING MACE
>  15. Red Garland's Essential **Quintet: "White Winter"** (5) **[EDGAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Winter)** = _ED GAR_
>  16. Obama binned a **piece of ceremonial attire** (4) **SASH** = [SASH(-a)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_Barack_Obama#Malia_Obama_and_Sasha_Obama)
>  18. Where some Floridians are | home and escape? (4) **KEYS** = ddef
>  20. Bananas lay at part of Russian-controlled territory (5) **[YALTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yalta)** = ATLAY*
>  23. Assimilate disheartened **minority group's member in Egypt** (4) **[COPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_Orthodox_Church)** = CO(-o)PT
>  25. Provide education for | way to transport people (5) **TRAIN** = ddef
>  26. Young adult to fly from Philippine island westward to get **substance used in some bars** (5) **CAROB** = [BORAC(-ay)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boracay)<
>  27. I was lost in silent **thoughtfulness** (4) **TACT** = TAC(-i)T
>  29. **Moral principle** on the Forum... and here (5) **ETHIC** = ET + HIC (‘and here’ in Latin, i.e. on ‘the Forum’!)
>  32. **Children wait for this in excitement** before parents kiss (1-3) **XMAS** = X (kiss) + MAS (parents)
>  36. Country girl making small oversight at the beginning (4) **LAOS** = LA(s → O)S
>  39. **She sailed with Nina**'s dad, having lost diamonds after some beer (5) **[PINTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinta_(ship))** = PINT + (-d)A(-d)
>  40. An unfair icon misrepresented multinational collective (7,5) **AFRICAN UNION** = ANUNFAIRICON*
>  42. **Exploration** of social science after end of semester (5) **RECON** = (-semeste)R + ECON
>  43. Primarily aviators' lingo for A? (4) **ALFA** = A_ L_ F_ A_ &lit!
>  44. **Foolish** deputee's head I shot exploded (6) **DOTISH** = D(-eputy) + ISHOT*
>
>  **Down**
>  1. Tour sea between Europe and Africa, **shaped like a hemisphere** (5) **DOMED** = DO (Tour) + MED
>  2. **Important figure in the story about Apple**, Mr Jobs? No saint! (3) **EVE** = (-st)EVE
>  3. **Predatory seabird** is the first to break the sound barrier, they say (6)  **JAEGER** = sounds like [YEAGER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Yeager)
>  4. Bananas lay at **part of Russian-controlled territory** (5) **[ALTAY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altai_Republic)** = ATLAY*
>  5. **Heraldic pattern** of very distinct quality (4) **[VAIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vair)** = V + AIR
>  6. Nubian leader welcomed aboard Mesopotamian kingdom's **vessels** (4) **URNS** = UR’S containing N(-ubian)
>  7. Story supported by NASA's top **astronomer** (5) **[SAGAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Sagan)** = SAGA + N(-asa)
>  8. Beginning to accept politician's **sources of feedback** (4) **AMPS** = A(-ccept) + MP’S
>  9. What a soccer lover has when playing? (1,4) **A BALL** = cdef
>  10. Rapper Ice-T entertaining **university in Texas** (4) **[RICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_University)** = _R ICE_
>  11. Cree occasionally visiting capital of Italy, large and **prosperous European country** (7) **IRELAND** = I(-taly) + _R_E + L + AND
>  17. **Broadway lyricist** Lerner's back in Panama? (4) **[HART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_Hart)** = HAT containing (-lerne)R
>  18. Leaving hotel, Kathy exchanged currency (4) **[KYAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myanmar_kyat)** = KAT(-h)Y*
>  19. "Pat", alternatively (3) **APT** = PAT* &lit!
>  21/41. I stop dancing, essentially; Stafford **blows the whistle** (4,3) **TIPS OFF** = ISTOP*  + (-sta)FF(-ord)
>  22. Cree occasionally visiting capital of Italy, large and **prosperous European country** (7) **ICELAND** = I(-taly) + C_E_ + L + AND
>  23. **Tesla created one; it runs on electricity,** carbon and fossil fuel (4) **[COIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_coil)** = C + OIL
>  24. "Pat", alternatively (3) **TAP** = PAT* &lit!
>  28. **Paper** animal haphazardly put together (6) **MANILA** = ANIMAL*
>  30. Repair short **block that has come up in faulty environment** (5) **HORST** = SHORT*
>  31. Provide education for | way to transport people (5) **COACH** = ddef
>  33. **Last name of Caribbean native who sings** remix of "Jammin'" without drum backing (5) **[MINAJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicki_Minaj)** = JAM(m)IN*
>  34. Maybe Hamlet is protecting a **legendary hero's mother** (5) **[DANAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dana%C3%AB)** = DAN(A)E
>  35. **Do** (or another note) coming up (4) **AFRO** = (OR+FA)<
>  37. **AA** assembly's introduction: "Dry wine is on the rise" (4) **ACES** = A(-ssembly) + SEC<
>  38. Rocker Scott's turned out to be **a pretentious type** (4) **SNOB** = [BON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bon_Scott)’S<
>  39. **Not at all like King Kong** climbing up the Empire State? (4) **PUNY** = UP< + NY
>  41. (See 21 down)

An appropriate name for this puzzle is:

> **DEJA VU (BY JAFE)** - this can be read off via the 6 dead-ends in the first and last rows of the crossword.
>
>  Er... Wait a sec, have I read that before somewhere...?!

Comment: Curses! Foiled again! :-)

Comment: Could I get further explanation for 19 down? :00

Comment: @oAlt Yup, both these words mean "exactly suited to the purpose or occasion" (see [MW definition 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pat))

Comment: Not only is it correct, it's also hilarious.